# People management tag wiki for the anniversary competition

Tags: discussion, tags

The [people-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people-management) tag didn't have a wiki so I drafted one based on my understanding of the questions.

This probably deserves some attention right now, so I'm posting my draft in the hope that it can be greatly improved upon.

> People matter to security from employees who are targets of social engineering, to architects & engineers who devise and implement security-critical policies. People management involves preventing these people from becoming part of an attack by filtering out bad actors (e.g. background checks), helping good actors act well (e.g. education), and, and preventing single points of failure (e.g. limits on intra-departmental communication).

Comment: I have added one piece of formatting (see if you can spot it on the wiki description) but other than that it works for me:-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop doesnt [tag:people-management] also include things like team management, business interface, etc?

Comment: @AviD - aye, that'd be good too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I incorporated @AviD's suggestions at https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/people-management/info by adding

> - managing people to help them balance security with other requirements
> - liasing between different organizations/divisions to ensure critical information reaches the people who need it.

and will now mark this question answered.